# How to pass date with SelectDateWidget?

Tags: django, widget

I'm trying to make this simple code to work:

## forms.py

```
class TestForm(forms.Form):
    start_date = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget())
    end_date = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget())
```

## views.py

```
def test(request):
    form = TestForm(request.GET)
    if form.is_valid():
        start = request.GET.get('start_date')
        end = request.GET.get('end_date')
        test_var = 'Hello'

    return render(request, 'schedule/test.html', locals())
```

## test.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <form method="get">
    <table>
        {{ form.as_table }}
        <tr><td><input type="submit"></td><td></td></tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    <br/>
    <b>Start date</b>: {{ start }}<br />
    <b>End date</b>: {{ end }}<br />
    <b>Test var:</b> {{ test_var }}


{% endblock %}
```

It looks that SelectDateWidget does not set {{ start }} and {{ end }} variables correctly:

---

[image: screenshot]

---

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

form values are accessed via cleaned data, try:

```
start = form.cleaned_data.get('start_date')
end = form.cleaned_data.get('end_date')
```

if you want the get parameters they are passed by day, month and year:

print: request.GET will give you:

```
<QueryDict: {u'end_date_day': [u'4'], u'start_date_day': [u'1'], u'end_date_year': [u'2012'], u'end_date_month': [u'3'], u'start_date_month': [u'2'], u'start_date_year': [u'2012']}>
```